# Should I place a Sub Header in or outside the header tag?

Tags: html

Is it semantically valid to place a `<div id="subHeader"></div>` inside or outside the `header` tag?

Inside:

```
<header>
    <!-- content -->
    <div id="subHeader"><div id="breadcrumbs"></div></div>
</header>
```

VS.

Outside:

```
<header>
    <!-- content -->
</header>
<div id="subHeader"></div>
```

Comment: You don't really have to use the header tag at all as far as I am concerned. If you are trying to do what I think you are, you probably want it inside though.

Comment: @AidanMueller I included the header tag as it is more descriptive for the purpose of the question. But the answer really applies generally speaking, even if not using a `header` tag. Any tag such as a div that is acting like a header, for example. Just not sure if it made more sense to have the subheader inside or outside the tag which represents the main header. Personally I find it easier to handle if the sub is outside, since it's easier to style and position (for me).

Comment: You have to think about HTML as a hierarchy. Is `subHeader` a part of the contents that make up the header? Then put it in the header. The `<header>` tag AFAIK is used to contain the navigation, logos, etc. of your site. If `subHeader` is part of that, then it wouldn't make sense to put it outside. If you ever want to, for example, move the whole header and its contents, you will have less hassle.

Comment: @AidanMueller Thanks. Well, the header and its content can stand on its own, in that sense. But the subHeader and its content is directly related to part of the content of header. Maybe an `aside` would be appropriate? :/

Comment: What do you mean by "directly related"? Is there a reason why you don't want it to be in the header?